# How to delete buttons on Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I really need to be able to delete a button onscreen into a label. All I need to do is remove the button, and put the label in place of it. However, I do not know how to remove buttons.

I am running Windows 10, Python 3.9.2.

Comment: Better to post some code, so we can work on something rather than assuming stuff.

Comment: FYI a `Button` *is* a widget.

Comment: @martineau I didn't understand what a widget was when I posted this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def remove_button():
    global label
    # Get the grid parameters passed in button when it was created
    button_grid_info = button.grid_info()
    button.grid_forget()
    label = tk.Label(button_grid_info["in"], text="This is a Label widget")
    # Put the label exactly where the button was:
    label.grid(**button_grid_info)

root = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Click me", command=remove_button)
button.grid(row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

`grid_forget` removes the widget without destroying it. If you used `<button>.pack`, use `pack_forget`. If you used `<button>.place`, use `place_forget`.

Comment: I will try this.

Comment: If, in OP case, the button is not the last widget in the container, then the label will not be put in the same position of the button.

Comment: @DaniyalWarraich try again I updated my answer to use `grid`/`grid_forget`

Comment: @acw1668 I fixed that. Now the label will appear exactly where the button was.

Comment: Nope. The button does not disappear. Plus, Python isn’t giving errors.

Comment: @DaniyalWarraich When running my code, the button doesn't disappear? If so then something is wrong with your tkinter.

Comment: Works. Thanks a lot!